# The SDK configured in dart.flutterSdkPath is not a valid SDK folder

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I'm using VScode to make a flutter app. After the flutter installation, I added flutter & dart extension to VScode. However, I'm Keep getting an error that "The SDK configured in dart.flutterSdkPath is not a valid SDK folder."
I'm trying to set up my path but still getting a same error message.

My flutter path is C:\src\flutter\bin,
and my settings.json has like this "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\src\flutter\bin"

It seems working well in android studio, but not in VScode. Please help how to solve this issue.
Many thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

just delete '\bin' bro. My Mac's path is: "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/name/development/flutter",